# How to run Sveltekit app on docker container on localhost

Tags: docker, sveltekit

I'm learning docker so I want to test a Sveltekit app locally on a docker container but I was unable to make it work. This is my setup:

**# svelte.config.js**

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
       adapter: adapter()
   }
};

export default config;
```

**# Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -rf build
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS run

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=build /app/build ./build
RUN npm install --production
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "build" ]
```

**# docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
   app:
    restart: always
    image: svelte-docker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: run
    ports:
      - 3000:5050
```

After I run `docker compose up -d` and open `localhost:3000`, I get `This site can’t be reached` error.

I don't know what I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing your last line with

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "build" ]
```

the folder `.build` does not exist you are creating a folder simply named `build` using `COPY --from=build /app/build ./build`

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just a typo. I fixed it but it still does not work

Comment: I just tried again and updated the ports in your docker-compose.yml
I used `5050:3000` and localhost:5050 is working. If you want to reach your app on localhost:3000 just use `3000:3000`

Comment: This works now it was a port issue as you mentioned. Thanks  a lot